# Edit saved data from database by using Ckeditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I used Ckeditor to publish articles and save it to the database. Is there a way to retrieve that data to Ckeditor so I could edit and update the article?

Comment: yes, a select query...

Comment: Hmm..yes it can be retrieve by select query but how can that retrieve data be edited by using Ckeditor or place that data on the textarea. Sorry I'm a beginner at Ckeditor.

Comment: ckeditor just wraps a textarea, you can  pre-populate the texaterea  with the results of the query.

Comment: I was worried that Ckeditor will include the html tag on the textarea turns out it didn't ^-^. Thanks @tim!